# Reading/Displaying different text files with one function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, file

I'm trying to build a notary of sorts. This notary will have different buttons and with the press of each button a different message of plain text will display in a custom div. I want all buttons to display different messages, but display them in the same div and when a different button is pressed, the former message will fade away and the new message will fade in.

I have a basic understanding of the jQuery.get() and this is my JS and HTML code that I've used to read/display one file in that custom div by clicking the button labeled "First":

```
function Answer() {
    jQuery.get("file.txt", function(text) {
        $(".answerBox").text(text);
    })
};

<body>
    <div class="content">
        
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="button" type="button" onclick="Answer()">First</button>
            <button class="button" type="button" onclick="Answer()">Second</button>

        </div>

        <div class="textBox">
            <div class="answerBox">Click Any Question Button</div>
        </div>



    </div>
</body>
```

The issue comes when clicking the button labeled "Second", it reads the same file.txt and displays the same message. I am puzzled as to how I can expand this single function to encompass all 300 some odd buttons I will need and yes, each button will display a different message and will be tied to a different txt file. I really don't want to rewrite this small function 300 some times and I know there is a better way I just cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

So I've just asked this question, but I've been digging a bit more and I think I may have found something useful. I've rewritten my JS function and HTML as:

`function Answer(file) {

```
let list = [];
url = "files/" + file
list.push(url);

if (list.includes(url)) {
    jQuery.get(url, function(text) {
        $(".answerBox").fadeOut(() => {
            $(".answerBox").text(text);
        })

        $(".answerBox").fadeIn(2000)

    });

    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button" type="button" onclick="Answer('file.txt')">First</button>
        <button class="button" type="button" onclick="Answer('file1.txt')">Second</button>

    </div>
```

`
This kinda solves my initial problem, but now I will need to make 300 instances of buttons in HTML. Is there any other way or is this the best I can do with what I know?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).